# Agda How to solve error: failed to solve the following constraints

Tags: agda

What is wrong with this code?

EDIT:
I'm sending all the code including dependencies, imports, flags, etc.

I can't figure out where the error might be. I would be very grateful if someone could direct me how to fix this error.

```
{-#  OPTIONS --type-in-type --without-K  #-}

module Basic where

Type = Set

data Path {A : Type} : A → A → Type where
  id : {M : A} → Path M M

_≃_ : {A : Type} → A → A → Type
_≃_ = Path

infix 9 _≃_

ap :  {A B : Type} {M N : A}
      (f : A → B) → Path{A} M N → Path{B} (f M) (f N)
ap f id = id

ap≃ : ∀ {A} {B : A → Type} {f g : (x : A) → B x} 
      → Path f g → {x : A} → Path (f x) (g x)
ap≃ α {x} = ap (\ f → f x) α

postulate 
   λ≃  : ∀ {A} {B : A → Type} {f g : (x : A) → B x}
      → ((x : A) → Path (f x) (g x))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to solve the following constraints:
  Has bigger sort: _44
  piSort _25 (λ _ → Set) = Set
  Has bigger sort: _25
```

Any help?

Comment: Hi. This looks like a fair question. Can you include dependencies, imports, and flags so that we can reproduce the error?

Comment: Hi. I'm sending all the code including dependencies, imports, flags, etc. 

I can't figure out where the error might be. I would be very grateful if someone could direct me how to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get quite the same error, but I got the file to check by annotating `A` with type `Type` in the type of `λ≃`:

```
postulate
   λ≃  : ∀ {A : Type} {B : A → Type} {f g : (x : A) → B x}
      → ((x : A) → Path (f x) (g x))
```

The error I saw comes about because Agda will usually assume that you might want to use universe polymorphism, and there happens to be nothing else in the type of `λ≃` that constrains `A` to the lowest universe `Type`.